# Spring Boot custom method annotation not working while using @Aspect

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, annotations, aspect

I am working on a spring boot application and  I am trying to implement a custom annotation to log execution time and memory used by the method annotated with my custom annotation. I am not able to make it work and have no clue why its not working. I have found similar posts and found various example but none of it work on my case.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

Please find my code details below:

**build.gradle dependencies :**

```
dependencies {

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'

implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'

implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server"
implementation 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-service-registry'
implementation 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client'


compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter'
implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub'
implementation 'com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage'
implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core'

implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0'
implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'

implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.4.3'
implementation 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.6.1'
implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'
implementation 'org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.1'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
implementation('com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8')

implementation 'org.dom4j:dom4j:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:3.0.4'

testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
//testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver'
```

}

**Custom annotation interface**:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogExecutionProfile {}
```

**Logging Aspect class**

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

@Around("@annotation(LogExecutionProfile) || execution(public * @LogExecutionProfile *.*(..)))")
public Object profileMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
    String className = methodSignature.getDeclaringType().getSimpleName();
    String methodName = methodSignature.getName();

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long memoryAtStart = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

    Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long memoryAtEnd = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

    log.debug("execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms"
            + " memory used: " + (memoryAtEnd - memoryAtStart) + " bytes of memory");

    return result;
}
```

}

**Service class :**

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @LogExecutionProfile
  public void someServiceMethod(){
     log.debug("service log");
     // service method logic
  } 

}
```

**Expected Result :**

```
service log
execution time: XX ms memory used: XX bytes of memory
```

**Actual Result :**

```
service log
```

I have also tried below :

**Example 1 :** Not Working

```
@Pointcut("execution(@com.example.LogExecutionProfile * *.*(..))")
public void annotatedMethod() {}

@Around("annotatedMethod()")
public Object profileMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
**
}
```

**Example 2 :** Not Working

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.example.LogExecutionProfile)")
public void annotatedMethod() {}

@Around("execution(* *(..)) && (annotatedMethod())")
public Object profileMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
**
}
```

**Example 3 :** Not Working

```
@Around("@annotation(com.example.LogExecutionProfile)")
public Object profileMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
**
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An aspect in spring AOP must be annotated by @Configuration and @Aspect . So change your LoggingAspect class with this class

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Configuration;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class LoggingAspect {

@Around("@annotation(LogExecutionProfile) || execution(public * @LogExecutionProfile *.*(..)))")
public Object profileMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
    String className = methodSignature.getDeclaringType().getSimpleName();
    String methodName = methodSignature.getName();

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long memoryAtStart = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

    Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long memoryAtEnd = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

    log.debug("execution time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms"
            + " memory used: " + (memoryAtEnd - memoryAtStart) + " bytes of memory");

    return result;
}
```

There is a sample aspect that you can use

```
package com.dpco.aop;

import com.dpco.business.exception.CustomException;
import com.dpco.logger.Logger4j;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;


@Aspect
@Configuration
public class LoggerAspect {

    @Autowired
    private Logger4j logger4j;

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.dpco.controller.*.*(..)) && @annotation(requestMapping)")
    public void controller(RequestMapping requestMapping){
    }


    @Around("controller(requestMapping)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint , RequestMapping requestMapping) throws Throwable {

            Object[] obj = joinPoint.getArgs();
            File file = new File("log.txt");
            Object object = null;
            try {
                if (file.createNewFile()) {
                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
                    fileWriter.write("\n\n-----------------------------------------this is the logger of project , you can see the methods that calls and information of them  in here------------------------------------\n\n");
                    fileWriter.close();
                }
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
                Date first = new Date();
                fileWriter.write("\n---------------------------------------" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "-------------------------------------------\n");
                fileWriter.write("path is : " + requestMapping.path()[0] + "\n");
                fileWriter.write("the method of request is :" + requestMapping.method()[0] + "\n");
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for (Object arg : obj) {
                    builder.append(arg.toString() + ",");
                }
                if(builder.length() != 0) {
                    builder.deleteCharAt(builder.indexOf(builder.toString()));
                }
                fileWriter.write("the arguments of this method is : " + builder.toString() + "\n");
                object = joinPoint.proceed();
                Date second = new Date();
                fileWriter.write("the milli seconds that left : " + String.valueOf(second.getTime() - first.getTime()));
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger4j.getLogger(e);
                throw new CustomException("hello", HttpStatus.MULTI_STATUS);
            }
            return object;

    }



}
```

This aspect will be executed around any method in controller package wich annotated by request mapping.

I think after using @Configuration up to your aspect class and omit @Component it will work correctly .